# SIGABRT after setting an object to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

The topic says it all. I have a dictionary of dictionaries(yes, it's a dictionaryception!) stored in `NSUserDefaults`. For some strage reason I get SIGABRT at main.m just right after setting an object to the dictionary. Here's the code:

```
planDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plan_%@", self.planName]];
pageOne = [planDict objectForKey:@"Page_1"];
pageTwo = [planDict objectForKey:@"Page_2"];
pageThree = [planDict objectForKey:@"Page_3"];
[pageOne setObject:@"The Object" forKey:@"First Key"];
[pageOne setObject:@"The Other Object" forKey:@"Second Key"];
//other setters
```

I've debugged it and it went well till the line `[pageOne setObject:@"TheObject" forKey:@"First Key"];`. When I stepped over it just crashed(SIGABRT in main.m).

Here's the log right before the crash:

```
(gdb) po planDict
{
  "Page_1" =     {
  };
  "Page_2" =     {
  };
  "Page_3" =     {
  };
}
(gdb) po pageOne
{
}
(gdb) po pageTwo
{
}
(gdb) po pageThree
{
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary returned by asking NSUserDefaults will be an immutable dictionary, as will any dictionaries within dictionaries etc.

So SETTING an object on the immutable dictionary will indeed throw a SIGABRT error as the object returned does not understand the method you sent to it.

You will want to create a mutable copy of the dictionary instead, and make a mutable copy of each contained dictionary within that dictionary.

Hope that sorts out your error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem is in saving the dictionaries, have you saved mutable dictionary?
you are being given an immutable dictionary, so you have to create a mutable copy to it.